# Android Quick Settings Tile Drop Down Menu

Tags: android

I want to make an application that does something in the background, and to control its behavior, I wanted to have a quick-settings tile.
I managed to get the toggle working just fine, but now I want to know if it is possible to have a 'drop down' menu for the user to be able to choose an option out of 3 possible options. (3 different modes for the 'on' state)

[Something like the wifi and bluetooth tiles here, that have that little arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKCE0.png)

Is this a feature only for system apps, or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/quick-settings-tiles-e3c22daf93a8) that unfortunately third party apps cannot use this feature.

Quote:

> Note: You’ll notice some of the system tiles have an additional UI that replaces the whole quick settings pane with a custom UI. Unfortunately, this isn’t available to third party tiles.